# Incorportaing text messages in a disaster management application

Tags: c#, sms-gateway

I need to incorporate text message update in my web app for diasater management. Being new to it, at this point, all i know is that GSMComm library can be used for this purpose which needs either a dedicated GSM modem or a GSM phone. What else do i require for the thing to work? about SMS Gateways etc?  I need an overview from where to actually start!!

Comment: You need to be more exhaustive on what you need. Are you looking for hardware to read text messages? Or ideas on an application to process them?

Comment: I want my computer, to retrive messages delieverd on the GSM phone connected to it via usb cable.

Comment: Ok, then try it out and get back here when you have a specific question. You might not get good answers here if you ask questions which are unspecific.